# Lazy loading custom subviews for UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

In `-collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:` I’m adding custom subviews to the UICollectionViewCell like this:

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    NSString *const cellIdentifier = @"cellIdentifier";
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    MyCustomViewClass *carouselView = [[MyCustomViewClass alloc] init];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:carouselView];            

    return cell;
}
```

According to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/Reference/Reference.html), `dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:forIndexPath:` “dequeues an existing cell if one is available or creates a new one based on the class or nib file you previously registered.”

The problem is that my implementation of `cellForItemAtIndexPath` is constantly creating new instances of `MyCustomViewClass`. Even though instances of the latter are removed from the collection view when they’re out of the screen, it still seems wrong to create a new one every single time `dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:forIndexPath:` is called.

My question is, given that `MyCustomViewClass` instances are graphics-intensive and take up memory, what’s the best way to lazily load them? Do I have to implement my own queue? Or shall I make it a subclass of UICollectionViewCell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea about what your MyCustomViewClass does but you can create a custom UICollectionViewCell that has already that CustomViewClass associated.

If your CustomViewClass extends UIView is simpler. And if you are using storyboards it is even more simple. In your storyboard you don't need to create a custom UICollectionViewCell just for that. You can drag an UIVIew to your CollectionViewCell and set the customView to MyCustomViewClass. This way it will only be created once and then it will be reused.

If your MyCustomViewClass has some kind of state (imagine that is a status bar with a percentage) you can reset that state you have to extend the UICollectionViewCell and override `prepareForReuse`.

Comment: That worked. I created a custom UICollectionViewCell, in its `initWithFrame` I created a MyCustomViewClass instance, and I then add it to the `contentView`. Performance improved a lot. Thanks!

Comment: @Eric no problem :). Don't forget you have the prepareForReuse if you want to do something after the cell being reused. It is really handy.

Answer (score 2):

Because you did this `MyCustomViewClass *carouselView = [[MyCustomViewClass alloc] init];`, everytime the system call `dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:forIndexPath:` it will create a new instance of `MyCustomViewClass` for you. So what you need to do is to check whether an instance of `MyCustomViewClass` has already been added to that cell, if not then create a new one.

Comment: Thanks, I tried that but it didn't work. All the cells that are returned from `dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier` have an empty `subviews` array (i.e. `cell.contentView.subviews` is always empty)